# Tabulator - Force setRenderMode to Standard

Tags: tabular

I can't seem to find the documentation on the page regarding setRenderMode. Due to another plugin I'm using concurrently, I need all the rows to be rendered in Standard mode, the ones on VirtualDOM behave oddly after rendered. Is there a function or a Setting to force setRenderMode to Standard, or a similar rendering mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable [standard mode](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/virtual-dom#overview) you have to set [virtualDom to false](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/options#table)

If you still have problems rendering the table you may try to force a `table.redraw();` as stated in the [FAQ](http://tabulator.info/faq)